# NameError: uninitialized constant AppName::Loader::ModelImport::MyModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a namespace issue. MyModel is just a normal Rails Model. However, my code seems to be namespacing it under the namespace I created, I need a way to reference it directly without the `AppName::Loader::ModelImport` namespace.

Error:

> > NameError: uninitialized constant AppName::Loader::ModelImport::MyModel

Rake task:

```
require 'csv'
require_relative '../appname/loader/model_import'


namespace :app_name do
  namespace :loader do

    desc "Loads data into Database"

    task model_import: :environment  do

      include AppName::Loader::ModelImport
    end
  end
end
```

Service Object

./appname/loader/model_import.rb

```
module AppName
  module Loader
    module ModelImport
      record_set = []

      file_name = File.join(Rails.root, 'lib','appname','loader','data' ,'data.txt')
      CSV.open(file_name, "r", { :col_sep => "\t", quote_char: nil, row_sep: "\r\r\n" }).each do |row|
        record_set << MyModel.new(
          company_name: row[1],
          address1: row[2],
          address2: row[3],
          city: row[4],
          state_code: row[5],
          zip_code: row[6]
          )
      end

      MyModel.import record_set
    end
  end
end
```

I tried:

::MyModel.new()

and also got the >>NameError: uninitialized constant MyModel, so I wonder if rails is not loading properly. However, I thought `task model_import: :environment  do` loads Rails.

My application.rb file has..

```
    config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("lib")
```

If I use Pry, I can see the 'Rails' constant is loaded. However, I can not access any of my models. For example, `User` does not load, nor any other.

#### Solution per comments by Tom Lord:

require needed to be evaluated after the environment has been loaded.

Comment: is `./appname/loader/model_import.rb` start at the root of your rails project?

Comment: In my lib folder of my app lib/appname/loader/model_import.rb

Comment: What is the purpose of your namespacing?  You just writing code inside a module.  But why?

Comment: To help me Organize the code

Comment: This is a simplified example

Comment: Your module doesn't make much sense, as you've written it. It doesn't define any methods -- So what are you trying to do by `include`ing it?

Comment: I think what has happened is the file is being **evaluated immediately** by the `require_relative` statement. And since this happens *before* the environment is loaded, it doesn't know what `MyModel` is.

Comment: To summarise... In answer to the actual question you asked: You can use `::MyModel` instead of `MyModel` to explicitly say "use the top level namespace". However, this won't actually solve your problem; you're asking the wrong question. What you need to do instead is ensure that the code is evaluated **after the environment has been loaded**. (For example, by actually defining a method inside the module, and invoking it inside the rake task. Or, by moving the `require_relative` to inside the take task.)

Answer (score 1):

If you write a module the code inside it may automagically get executed just because you required the module.  For example:

```
module AppName
  module Loader
    module ModelImport
      puts 'wtf' # this may get run but you won't see it
    end
  end
end
```

However if you have at least method defined it can be called

```
module AppName
  module Loader
    module ModelImport
      def self.wtf
        puts 'wtf'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now if this file is saved in `lib/app_name/loder/model_import.rb` you can run it like this:

```
require_or_load 'lib/app_name/loader/model_import'
# and now you can do
AppName::Loader::ModelImport.wtf
=>wtf
```

So you need to first define a usable module, then you can require it, then you can call methods on it.

Comment: While you are correct I think the issue the OP is referring to is a constant lookup issue e.g. `MyModel` vs `::MyModel` as mentioned by [@TomLord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57464198/nameerror-uninitialized-constant-appnameloadermodelimportmymodel#comment101402961_57464198)

Comment: Good recommendation too, I did both, moved my require, and added a new method. It works now